# How to parse Place Details API JSON

Tags: java, android, json, google-places-api

I am trying to fetch value of "formatted_phone_number" but every time it returns null. Though it works for some keys like "formatted_address".

I am using `org.json.JSONObject`

This is my code -

```
    JSONObject jObject = null;   
    String result = null;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONObject jObjectResult = (JSONObject) jObject.get("result");
        result = jObjectResult.getString("formatted_phone_number");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Sample JSON Data -
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Let me know what I am doing wrong here and also is there any better way for this?

Comment: Consider using Gson before? It makes conversion from JSON to class object seamless, and vice versa.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: @Elye Thanks I'll check more about GSON

Comment: @SergeSeredenko result is always null though it works for formatted_address

Comment: @MandeepRajpal are you sure that field is in the data? print `jObjectResult.toString()` and make sure there is fomatted phone.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko okay I debugged and found that formatted_phone_number is in jObject inside "result" but not in jObjectResult. Please refer to sample JSON I can't paste that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the code as your question, and use the JSON as per the link. They works perfectly fine. Suggest you debug your input `jsonData` data content.

Anyway, for using GSON, it's as below (based your the JSON format you are checking.

Define the class model object matching the JSON

```
public class MyData {
    Result result;

    Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

public class Result {
    String formatted_phone_number;

    String getPhone() {
        return formatted_phone_number;
    }

}
```

And then use it as below.

```
    MyData mydata = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, MyData.class);
    String myPhone = mydata.getResult().getPhone();
```

You'll get the data auto parsed into your object. As you expand your class model structure (e.g. formatted_address, rating etc), you'll magically get them as well. Hope this ease your job. Cheers!

Comment: I'll definitely give this a try. This looks far more easy and efficient. But still just out of curiosity what is wrong with my JSON code and why it is not working for me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code posted above. I have tested it's good, if your json string given is exactly as per the link you have given. It could be some other things. I would suggest you dump out your Json String obtain, and check the keyword if they are matched.